# Why can I build this package (aspectC) in Ubuntu, but not Cygwin?

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to get started with [this](https://sites.google.com/a/gapp.msrg.utoronto.ca/aspectc/download) library and following the directions on that page, Cygwin returns [this](http://pastebin.com/xWyc7zYq), despite the project's page claiming to support Cygwin.

The Makefile works just fine in a fresh Ubuntu VM, and I've run Cygwin's setup.exe to include Devel, Interpreters, Perl, etc. which I thought may have fixed a broken dependency, but it won't build after installing all of the relevant packages.

Has anyone run into an issue like this before? Do you have any advice?

**Update**: The previous output was the result of me trying 0.8. I re-ran the 0.9RC Makefile and the problem seems to be:

```
/usr/local/bin/ACC/src/.acc_dir/matchaa_ac.c:63:1: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘__ac__type__insert’
/usr/local/bin/ACC/src/.acc_dir/matchaa_ac.c:63:1: error: stray ‘@’ in program
```

I can't think of why Cygwin is choking on the '@' character. Google is useless because it doesn't parse special characters.

Comment: What problems or error messages do you encounter? "Won't build" isn't very specific.

Comment: I've linked to the output of the make script in my post, but I'll reference it [here](http://pastebin.com/xWyc7zYq) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is:

```
/usr/local/bin/ACC/src/.acc_dir/matchinfo_ac.c:180:39: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PointcutType’
```

I would take a look at line 180 character 39 of `matchinfo_ac.c` for clues as to what is different between your two build environments.  Since the error is output by `tacc`, perhaps you need a later version of `tacc` to build `tacc`?  Syntax changes?  From v0.9 RC (note it is a development version)

```
struct _IO_FILE_plus ;
```

but be certain to check your own copy.  Anyways, this line doesn't have 39 characters.

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I had tried 0.8 as well, wondering if my issue was 0.9RC specific, but that's the output I placed above. 0.9RC actually gives messages about 'error: stray ‘@’ in program' all over. I'm no C expert, but I don't see how the compiler would have a problem with the '@' char. Unfortunately, Google doesn't work with symbols so there's not a lot of literature that I can find.

Comment: tacc is bundled with ACC, so wouldn't it have the correct version?

Comment: Take a look at the lines with the errors.  My copy of `matchaa_ac.c` doesn't even have an @ until line 1466.  Perhaps there is a file encoding issue?